# How do I fully share a Hard Drive on my Local Network?

Tags: windows-7, home-networking, file-sharing

I have 4 computers connected to a router (DD-WRT)

My main PC is Windows 7 (Home Premium). This machine has 2 Hard Disks: HD1 is used for my OS and the other (HD2) is used to store files. My 3 other machines are 1. Ubuntu Destop that I use to learn about linux, 2. A Mac OSX laptop, and 3. A netbook running windows 7.

**How do I easily share HD2 with my other machines?** I would like all my machines to have full access & permissions to HD2 *however* I would like to RESTRICT access to only PCs that are connected to my router (either via LAN and WiFi) --- btw, I know this is not very  secure due to WiFi vulnerability , however, I currently MAC address restrict WiFi connections my router.

Extra Info: I have already tried to use the Windows Folder Sharing feature: i.e. I right click over the icon of HD2, and click on the Sharing Tab, but in sub-window labeled "Network File and Folder Sharing", the "Share" button is grayed out. I can click on "Advanced Shared" but that just takes me to a screen in which I have to set certain permissions. What is not clear to me is: **How do I set a criteria that shares HD2 with all computer connected to my router?**

Comment: have you tried setting it to be ok to share with the guest user?

Comment: @Kravlin: I guess I could try that, but would that accomplish my goal of limiting access to only PCs connected to my router? Also would that make the HD available to my Mac and to my linux machine?

Answer (score 0):

Just add group ***Everyone***, and give it a ***Read/Write*** permission level.

[image]